# deleting zero from string in prolog

Tags: string, prolog

there is my problem that I can't solve on prolog

Enter a string from the keyboard. Remove from each group of digits, which is not preceded by a dot, all initial zeros (except the last one), if there is a point after it. For example: from the line "000.0010" you must make "0.0010"

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What is not working with your approach?

Comment: What part are you having trouble with?

Comment: "Can anyone help me with this?" Yes, someone surely can help you with this. You can help us help you by reading here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions and also here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and then writing a good question. What you have at the moment is not a good question.